# jpa entity - getter doesn't bring the correct result

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm working with Jpa, Hibernate.
I have a very weird thing happening in my project.
I have 2 entities: student and course, many to many relationship.
For a long time everything worked perfectly, and suddenly I have this problem:
When I find a specific student (em.find) and then return its list of courses, using the getter (student.getCourses) I receive only part of the list! and if I do it with a query ("select s.courses from Students s where id = ...") - it gives the correct result.
I tried to solve it for a long time - and nothing.
Anyone has an idea of what the problem could be?
Any help would be highly appreciated!
Here is my code:

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Course
 *
 */
@Entity(name = "Courses")

public class Course extends Stamping {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String courseName;
@Version
@Column(name = "Version", nullable = false)
private Long version;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "LecturerID")
private Lecturer lecturer;


public Course() {
    super();
    this.courseName = " ";

}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public Lecturer getLecturer() {
    return lecturer;
}

public void setLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
    this.lecturer = lecturer;
}

public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}


public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

}

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Student
 *
 */
@Entity

public class Student extends Person /*and Person class extends Stamping*/{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 2)
private E_Year studentYear;
private Boolean inCondition;

@ManyToMany(cascade = PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();

public Student() {
    super();
    this.inCondition = true;
}

public E_Year getStudentYear() {
    return studentYear;
}

public void setStudentYear(E_Year studentYear) {
    this.studentYear = studentYear;
}

public Boolean getInCondition() {
    return inCondition;
}

public void setInCondition(Boolean inCondition) {
    this.inCondition = inCondition;
}


public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}
```

}

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Stamping
 *
 */
@MappedSuperclass

public class Stamping implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
private Date created;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "updated", nullable = false)
private Date updated;

private String lastUser;

public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public Date getUpdated() {
    return updated;
}

public String getLastUser() {
    return lastUser;
}

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    updated = created = new Date();
    lastUser = System.getProperty("user.name"); 
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    updated = new Date();
    lastUser = System.getProperty("user.name"); 
}

public Stamping() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((created == null) ? 0 : created.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastUser == null) ? 0 : lastUser.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((updated == null) ? 0 : updated.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Stamping other = (Stamping) obj;
    if (created == null) {
        if (other.created != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!created.equals(other.created))
        return false;
    if (lastUser == null) {
        if (other.lastUser != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastUser.equals(other.lastUser))
        return false;
    if (updated == null) {
        if (other.updated != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!updated.equals(other.updated))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Please, post classes for Student, Course and DAO class.

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved...
I found out it all happened because I had a base class for both student and course, and it had   HashCode and Equals methods generated from Eclipse.
After removing these methods everything works fine.
Can anyone explain why it happens?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that the code with or without the problem? I don't see any obvious cause of the problem. Maybe turn on query logging and comparing the executed queries will help.

Comment: It's the code with the problem. I'll try what you told me. thanks.